# Use Theme.Light background as LinearLayout background

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

I'm currently working on a list view like the list view used in 'People'. I'm using the [StickyListHeaders](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders) library but I'm having problems styling the list headers themselves.

At the moment, this is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:textColor="@color/ugent_blue_dark"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <View
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/ugent_blue_light">
    </View>

</LinearLayout>
```

What I want to achieve, as said before is a list view like the 'people' view. At this moment, the LinearLayout is transparant. I want to fix this by using a background property on the LinearLayout. To 'blend in' with the background, it would have to use the same background as the theme I'm using. For clarification: I don't want it to become transparant, that's why I'm trying to apply a background.
Now this is where I have problems with: The theme I'm using has as parent `Theme.Sherlock.Light` which has as parent `android:Theme.Light`.

If you look at the screenshot; you can see that the bar with '12 Feb' is transparant. I want it to have the same background as the rest of the app.

[image]

So, my question is: What `background:` do I need to apply on the LinearLayout to make it have the same background as the background of my app?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

if u using light then simply put the image as light! if holo put the background as dark. 
P.S i can't know which code is controlling the above layout theme ! to make it transparent but sure if its not set on `styles` then check the class to see if its customized from there !

Comment: 'put the image as light'? There is no image.